# How to check CSS Box model of an element in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, cypress, jquery-terminal

I plan to create visual testing for my library jQuery Terminal. But I need to know, if it's possible to check the CSS box model (margin, padding, width, and height) of the elements.

I need to check if the CSS is working as it should, sice I unintentionally introduced bugs, like spacing before an image caused by `::before` pseudo element or invalid width of the span that contained wider characters (like Chinese or Japanese). Can you test stuff like this with Cypress?

I was searching but was not able to find any information. There is [DOM API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/dom) but I don't see size.